# how do you install memcache into your server?

Tags: php, optimization, memcached

sorry im a newbie, i dont know if i am asking the right question, i just wanted to optimise my sites perfomance!! thanks in advance

Comment: You realize this is a Yes/No question, do you? Please [refine the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3545688/edit) to ask specifically about the parts you've got issues with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you use the memcached pecl extension: http://php.net/memcache

Comment: thank you very much!! and do you have to install this into your server or is it just matter of adding code!!! thanks again

Comment: But you have to configure php to use the memcache extension module, e.g. by putting something like `extension=php_memchache.so` into your php.ini.